# SP2013 - KeywordQuery search profile by Birthday field

Tags: 2013, keywordquery

I need search people profile by Birthday field using KeywordQuery. The field is indexed correctly, when I search for REST, 
`/_api/search/query?querytext='*'&sourceid='B09A7990-05EA-4AF9-81EF-EDFAB16C4E31'&rowlimit=6&selectproperties='PreferredName,Birthday'&refinementfilters='Birthday:range(datetime("2000-11-20"),%20datetime("2000-11-24"))'`, works fine.
But when I try search using KeywordQuery, returns error: 
"The research found a problem that prevents the return of results. If the problem persists, contact your administrator."

My code:

```
KeywordQuery keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(SPContext.Current.Site);
keywordQuery.SourceId = new Guid("B09A7990-05EA-4AF9-81EF-EDFAB16C4E31");
keywordQuery.HiddenConstraints = "scope:\"People\"";                                        
keywordQuery.TrimDuplicates = true;
keywordQuery.EnableStemming = true;
keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("Birthday");
keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("LastModifiedTime");
**keywordQuery.QueryText = "Birthday:November 21";**
keywordQuery.RowLimit = 200;
SearchExecutor searchExecutor = new SearchExecutor();
ResultTableCollection results = searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(keywordQuery);
```

My filter tests:

Works:

```
keywordQuery.QueryText = "LastModifiedTime:2013-11-21";
keywordQuery.QueryText = "PreferredName:Someone*";
```

Don't work:

```
keywordQuery.QueryText = "Birthday:November 21";
keywordQuery.QueryText = "Birthday:datetime(\"11-21-2000T00:00:00Z\")";
keywordQuery.QueryText = "Birthday:range(datetime(\"11-01-2000T00:00:00Z\"), datetime(\"11-30-2000T00:00:00Z\"))";
keywordQuery.QueryText = "Birthday:2000-11-21";
keywordQuery.QueryText = "Birthday:2000-21-11";
keywordQuery.QueryText = "Birthday:11-21";
keywordQuery.QueryText = "Birthday:21-11";
```

Does anyone know how to filter the search for the birthday field?

Answer (score 2):

In your example you search for * in the fulltextindex in the rest api, and apply refinement filter for a date range on birthday field. Did the rest api return any refinement results for birthday? I assume you have already verified that your search schema is correct, birthday is queriable and refineable. In your c# example you don't perform the same query as in the rest example. For trouble shooting I recommended the SharePoint 2013 Search Query Tool on codeplex.

Have you tried the fielded search in the rest api? Without refinement

Comment: My REST url returns OK. My problem is with the KeywordQuery.

Comment: What I was trying to say is that none of your c# examples use the same query as your rest example. Try keywordQuery.QueryText = "*"; and add your birthday refiner using keywordQuery.RefinementFilters.Add(...)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my english.
just now i see your post,
after to you checked all details of Petter Skodvin-Hvammen and check if you are permission to the files that you search ,
and this propbleme persist ,
you can try to test it directly to searchbox webpart and not must to write code 
and check it face to debugger .
you can try to write  "Birthday:\"November 21\"" (for c#) or
Birthday:"November 21" for searchbox webpart and not "Birthday:November 21"
because space between two word in kql can  problematicaly .